# Rating Bar gets 0 in recycler view

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

In my app I have a recycler view that holds a name and address of a restaurant and I just tried to add a rating bar to it and I get all the data from SQL database and I use volley for connecting to it, every thing works fine and I can even send a rating for a restaurant but when I try to get the data I get 0
and I checked the REST API and Json, when I set the rating with a final value without database in my Recycler adapter class It works but when I try to set the data in my MainActivity and geting it in my on bindview holder it gets 0 please help

MainActivty

```
public void sendRequest(){

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, request_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                restaurants.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        restaurant.setId(jsonObject.getInt("restaurant_id"));
                        restaurant.setName(jsonObject.getString("restaurant_name"));
                        restaurant.setAddress(jsonObject.getString("restaurant_address"));
                        restaurant.setImage(jsonObject.getInt("restaurant_image_type"));
                        restaurant.setHasNote(jsonObject.getBoolean("restaurant_has_note"));
                        restaurant.setRating((float) jsonObject.getInt("restaurant_rating"));
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        Log.i("VolleyGetError",e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    restaurants.add(restaurant);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    shimmerContainer.stopShimmerAnimation();
                    shimmerContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                fastfoodRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("Volley Error:", String.valueOf(error));
            }
        });
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    }
```

My POJO class

```
public Restaurant() {
    }

    public Restaurant(String name, String address,int type){
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Restaurant(int id, String name, String address,int type){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Restaurant(int id,  String name, String address, int type,int image,int count) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.type = type;
        this.image = image;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public Restaurant(int id,  String name, String address, int type,int image,int count,float rating) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.type = type;
        this.image = image;
        this.count = count;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public float getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setRating(float rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public void setCount (int count) {this.count = count;}

    public int getId() { return id;}

    public void  setId (int id) { this.id = id;}

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;}

    public boolean isHasNote(){
        return hasNote;
    }

    public void setHasNote(boolean hasNote){
        this.hasNote = hasNote;
    }

    public String getAddress() { return address;}

    public void setAddress(String address) { this.address = address;}

    public void setType(int type) {this.type = type;}

    public int getType() {return type;}

    public int getImage() {return image;}

    public void setImage(int image) {this.image = image;}
}
```

my Recycler Adapter class

```
        TextView listviewName,listviewAddress;
        ImageView icon,noteIcon,deleteicon;
        RelativeLayout viewBackground, viewForeground;
        RatingBar ratingBar;

        MyViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            ratingBar = view.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);
            listviewName = view.findViewById(R.id.listview_name);
            listviewAddress = view.findViewById(R.id.listview_address);
            icon = view.findViewById(R.id.type_ic);
            noteIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.note_icon);
            deleteicon = view.findViewById(R.id.delete_icon);
            deleteicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewBackground = view.findViewById(R.id.view_background);
            viewForeground = view.findViewById(R.id.view_foreground);
            view.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onRestaurantSelected(restaurantListFiltered.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
            menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Edit");
            menu.add(0, 2, 1, "Remove");
            menu.add(0, 3, 2, "Add Note");
            menu.add(0, 4, 3, "All Notes");
        }
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fadein);
        itemView.startAnimation(animation);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                setPosition(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                return false;
            }
        });
        Restaurant restaurant = restaurantList.get(position);
        holder.listviewName.setText(restaurant.getName());
        holder.listviewAddress.setText(restaurant.getAddress());
        holder.ratingBar.setRating(restaurant.getRating());
        switch (restaurant.getImage()) {
            case RestaurantContract.EntryRestaurants.RESTAURANT_TYPE_DELIVERY:
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.phoneorderr);
                break;
            case RestaurantContract.EntryRestaurants.RESTAURANT_TYPE_SITDOWN:
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.sitdownn);
                break;
            case RestaurantContract.EntryRestaurants.RESTAURANT_TYPE_TAKEAWAY:
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.takeaway);
                break;
        }
        holder.noteIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.notepadicon);
        if(restaurant.isHasNote()) {
            holder.noteIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            holder.noteIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }
```

My json

```
    {
        "restaurant_id": "97",
        "restaurant_name": "tt",
        "restaurant_address": "rr",
        "restaurant_type": "0",
        "restaurant_has_note": "0",
        "restaurant_image_type": "2",
        "restaurant_rating": "3"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you've your POJO class as `Restaurant`. Add below value to your `rating` field

```
public Restaurant(){
public float rating = 0.0f;
}
```

Secondly, you'll need to listen your rating bar changes on your `MyViewHolder` like below:

```
  ratingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);
        ratingBar .setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            restaurants.get(getPosition()).rating = ratingBar.getRating();
        }
    });
```

I see you've already implemented an `arraylist` with the name of `restaurantList`, i've still mentioned the implementation below for reference:

Then in your Adapter you'll have to implement an `arraylist` to fetch the data for your `ratingBar`

```
static List<Restaurant> restaurants= new ArrayList<>(); //restaurantList in your
```

Initiate it in your constructor.

```
this.restaurants = restaurants;//restaurantList in your case
```

Then in your `onBindViewHolder`

```
List<String> restro= new ArrayList<String>();

     for(int i=0;i<restaurants.size();i++){
        restro.add(String.valueOf(restaurants.rating));//restaurantList in your case
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: first of all thanks for your reply im kind a new in android so if asked a stupid question forgive me you said i have to set rating to 0.0f in my pojo class but i only have setter and getter in my pojo class and in my pojo class constructor im setting the variabls and my other question is i use volley and use jsonobject.get int and i cast it to float do i have to change that or its ok?? Best of regards

Comment: Hi @kasra don't hesitate to ask any question which comes to your mind. You need to declare the rating value in your POJO class the same way i've mentioned, its just that you're giving some value to it. Next about jsonobject.get int - this needs to be something which has to be done after you send and fetch the ratings successfully in sharedpreferences. In order to do that i'd suggest you to refer this page https://abhiandroid.com/programming/shared-preference  after which you could get the same value and put it in your json object and pass it in webservice. Feel free to ask any question again.